# htaccess to redirect to another directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

i have the example website:

> example.com

i have a blog folder on this website and i also have another folder with the exactly same files as the root(its a translated folder)

> example.com/en/

I need to redirect users that click on my banner to the root blog folder, using the same atributes as he clicked.

for example:

he clicks on a blog post in the /en/ folder

> example.com/en/blog/eventos_21_example-post

i need to add something on htaccess to redirect this link to

> example.com/blog/eventos_21_example-post

It needs to be something that works for every post.

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^es/(blog/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /es/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: im seeing here now, that it is not working with all links. what could be?

Comment: This link works: example.com/blog/eventos_227_frias-no-clima-de-copa                                                                   This isnt: example.com/en/blog/educacional_223_a-colonia-kids-do-vale-verde-vai-ser-show-de-bola                                           its redirecting to /es/blog

Comment: I suspect you have some other rule that is misbehaving. Above rule is pretty simple and will work in both the cases. Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Rules look fine to me. Is there any .htaccess in `/es/blog` also?

Comment: Hmm ok. What happens when you open `example.com/es/blog/eventos_227_frias-no-clima-de-copa`

Comment: the page doesnt exists

Comment: And did it change URL in browser to `example.com/blog/eventos_227_frias-no-clima-de-copa` by removing `/es` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45507/discussion-between-lucca-zenobio-and-anubhava)